# Using two different inputs for a class constructor

Tags: java, string, class, object, constructor

I am coding a program where I need multiple different classes to record information about an employee. This information includes an employee number, a name, an address, and a hire date. I have already finished the employee number class, but I am having trouble with my Name class. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AssignmentTen
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {   
        int input1 = getInt ("Enter Employee Number:");
        Employee e1 = new Employee(input1);
        System.out.println(e1.number);

        Name n1 = new Name();
        System.out.println(n1.firstName + " " + n1.lastName);
    }

    public static int getInt(String paramString)
    {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(paramString);
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}

class Employee
{
    int number;

    Employee(int newNumber)
    {
        number = newNumber;
    }
}

class Name
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
```

How can I get the statement where Name n1 is created to incorporate a first and a last name? I want both names to be recorded via user input individually, but have them both combined to make the Name object.

Basically, I want the First Name and the Last Name to be individual input strings, but have them both put together when Name n1 is created. Can anyone tell me how I should go about doing that?

Comment: "have them both put together when Name n1 is created" -- Do you mean combined into one String?

Comment: I don't understand. Your Name class already has individual strings for first name and last name. Just add a constructor with two arguments and that's it!

Comment: @david If that would result in the two looking like a full name in the command line, then yes.

Comment: @isnot2bad How would I do that? Would it look like 'Name n1 = new Name (firstName, lastName);'? Sorry, I'm just really new to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main method..

```
    String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter firstname");
    String lastName =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter lastname");      
    Name n1 = new Name(firstName,lastName);
    System.out.println(n1.firstName + " " + n1.lastName);
```

And in Name class

```
static class Name {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(String firstName,String lastName){
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think while creating Name Object you should restrict user by constructor to pass both name.

```
class Name
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public Name(String fname,String lname){
         this.firstName = fname;
         this.lastName = lname;
    }
}
```

So Name Object must have this properties value.

Answer (score 0):

Define a constructor for the `Name` class that takes two arguments,  the first name and the last name as shown by @SubhrajyotiMajumder.

Then ask for the user to input the two names and use them to construct a `Name` object:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter first name : ");
String firstName = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter last name : ");
String lastName = sc.nextLine();

Name n1 = new Name(firstName, lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a two-argument-constructor like that:

```
class Name {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public Name(String first, String last) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
    }
}
```